# creating space for data with fdisk

Tags: partition, fdisk, hyper-v

I am running a debian server on Windows in Hyper-V, I have expanded the Hyper-V partition to 2T, now I would like to expand the Debian partition to use that new space. The new space will be for videos, so I am thinking the easiest thing to do is simply create a new partition and mount that and save the video in the partition.  I am running from the cmd line, so I need some assistence in creating the partition.  I have both fdisk and parted install.  Here is the current state of things:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2 TiB, 2199023255552 bytes, 4294967296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8427e4f2

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 266336255 265834498 126.8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 266336255 265834496 126.8G 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.



Disk /dev/mapper/UniFiServer--vg-root: 124.8 GiB, 133957681152 bytes, 261636096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/UniFiServer--vg-swap_1: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

---

I have made some progress, it appears that I succeeded in using parted to actually extend /dev/sda2 & /dev/sda5 and with the help of Romeo, used pvresize to extend them to show 2T, now I just need some help on actually creating something I can use, the lvcreate command isn't working:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2 TiB, 2199023255552 bytes, 4294967296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x8427e4f2

Device     Boot  Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048     499711     497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 4294921875 4294420118    2T  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 4294921875 4294420116    2T 8e Linux LVM

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/mapper/UniFiServer--vg-root: 124.8 GiB, 133957681152 bytes, 261636096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/UniFiServer--vg-swap_1: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

$ sudo vgs
VG             #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
UniFiServer-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 2.00t 1.88t

$ sudo lvcreate -L 1.88t --name videodata UniFiServer--vg
  Volume group "UniFiServer--vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group UniFiServer--vg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `pvresize` to extend the PV

```
pvresize /dev/sda5
```

Then you can check the new size of VG

```
vgs
```

Then you can create new LV

```
lvcreate -L <size of the new volume> --name <name of volume> UniFiServer-vg
```

Then you should format and mount this new volume. And do not forget to edit `/etcfstab` to mount it on every boot

Comment: When I do the pvresize command, it says "1 physical volume(s) resized / 0 physical volume(s) not resized" and vgs returns the same VSize of 126.76g.  Don't I need to use fdisk to extend the logical partition or something first?

Comment: check with `pws` if PV is really resized and how much

Comment: @SamCarleton, will edit my answer to make your last command successful